# Grails Export Plugin errors

Tags: grails

I have a blank (brand new) Grails 2.3.8 project on which I am trying to learn how to use the export plugin and so far I just added this line:

```
compile ":export:1.6"
```

to my BuildConfig.goovy and some mime types to my Config.groovy:

```
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
atom:          'application/atom+xml',
css:           'text/css',
csv:           'text/csv',
form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
js:            'text/javascript',
pdf:            'application/pdf',
rtf:            'application/rtf',
excel:          'application/vnd.ms-excel',
ods:            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
rss:           'application/rss+xml',
text:          'text/plain',
hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
```

and tried to run the app but got these errors:

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-  java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the     full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-     java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the     full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the     full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral   (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

`grailsCentral()` is uncommented in my repositories. Here is a dependency report:

```
build - Dependencies for the build system only (total: 34)
+--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.3.8
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|    \--- jline:jline:2.11
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.4
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0
|    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    \--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0
|    \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.grails:grails-scripts:2.3.8
|    \--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    \--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.3.8
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.52.1
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.52
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.52
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:7.0.52
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.52


provided - Dependencies needed at development time, but not during deployment (total: 1)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1

| Error Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (scope: compile) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

compile - Dependencies placed on the classpath for compilation (total: 78)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.3.8
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.3.8
|         \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|         \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- junit:junit:4.11
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|         \--- commons-el:commons-el:1.0
|         \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.3.8
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.3.8
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.3.8
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.3.8
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.3.8
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.8.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.3.8
|    \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.1.0
|         \--- org.multiverse:multiverse-core:0.7.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.3.8
+--- org.grails.plugins:export:1.6
|    \--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|         \--- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.38
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext-rtf:2.1.7
|    >>>> org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.8.5
|    \--- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.0.3
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1

| Error Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (scope: runtime) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

runtime - Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (total: 111)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.3.8
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.3.8
|         \--- taglibs:standard:1.1.2
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.3.8
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.7.4
|         \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|         \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- junit:junit:4.11
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|         \--- javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2
|         \--- commons-el:commons-el:1.0
|         \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.3.8
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.3.8
|         \--- oro:oro:2.0.8
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- asm:asm:3.3.1
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.3.8
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.3.8
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.3.8
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.8.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.3.8
|    \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.1.0
|         \--- org.multiverse:multiverse-core:0.7.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.3.8
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.173
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.3.8
+--- org.grails.plugins:export:1.6
|    \--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.0
|         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
|    \--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|         \--- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.38
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext-rtf:2.1.7
|    >>>> org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.8.5
|    \--- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.0.3
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.13
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.7

| Error Could not find artifact org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.5 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (scope: test) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

test - Dependencies needed for test compilation and execution but not at runtime (total: 116)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.3.8
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.8.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.3.8
|         \--- taglibs:standard:1.1.2
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.3.8
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.7.4
|         \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|         \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.7.4
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- junit:junit:4.11
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|         \--- javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2
|         \--- commons-el:commons-el:1.0
|         \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.3.8
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.3.8
|         \--- oro:oro:2.0.8
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.3.8
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- asm:asm:3.3.1
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|         \--- cglib:cglib:2.2.2
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.8.RELEASE
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.3.8
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.3.8
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.3.8
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.8.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.3.8
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.3.8
|    \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.1.0
|         \--- org.multiverse:multiverse-core:0.7.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.3.8
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.3.8
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-test:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-mimetypes:2.3.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-converters:2.3.8
+--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.173
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.3.8
+--- org.grails.plugins:export:1.6
|    \--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.0
|         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
|    \--- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|         \--- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
|              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.38
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext-rtf:2.1.7
|    >>>> org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.8.5
|    \--- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.0.3
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.2
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.13
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|         \--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.0.6.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.0.6.RELEASE
|              \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.8.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.0.6.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:3.6.10.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.7
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to this link https://jira.grails.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GPEXPORT-28

You can fix it through a workaround. Add this in the `Buildconfig.Groovy`

```
repositories {
...
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
}

dependencies { 
...
compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
}
```

Apparently custom repositories are not propagated to Projects from plugins.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I was surprised this wasn't documented on the plugin page despite someone having recommended just that on the JIRA.

Comment: I have problems with this solution ... when i do that then i get Could not find artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:zip:1.9.2 in grailsCentral

Comment: UPDATED: It was my fault. I didn't realize that i should put it under "dependencies". It works!